# 2D array operation in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array, I want the element `i` of the array in every row to be reduced by element `i-1` in the same row

I've tried this code:

```
data = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
print(data)
for row in data:
    for cell in row:
        data[cell] = data[cell]-data[cell-1]

print(data)
```

and i got an output like this

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/testing/test.py", line 55, in <module>
    data[cell] = data[cell]-data[cell-1]

IndexError: index -8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

and i want output like this

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]

[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]
```

the main process was `data[i] = data[i]-data[i-1]`. i need this process for huge scale of data like more than 1024x1024 so i need something efficient

Comment: What do you want to do about the first element in a row?

Comment: @mrzo whatever, reduced by 0 or eliminated

Comment: Print `row` and `cell` inside the loops to better understand how they work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can slice both arrays and subtract:

```
data[:,1:] - data[:,:-1]

array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Or taking the [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html):

```
np.diff(data)
```